# Collect the elements from a list by categories

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elemets with different variables {a,b,c,A,B,C},

```
list={3 b, A Cos[c]^2 Sin[a] Sin[b], -a E^(I a c) f[C, A]}
```

Where f is some function. By assuming a, b, c, and integers are one category and A, B, C are the other category, I want everything associates with (a b c, and integers) to be in the first list, and the other to be in the second list. so  I want to divide this list by the two groups such that {group1,group2}.

```
(*{group1,group2}*)
(*1 means there is no element in the list for the category*)

{{3 b, Cos[c]^2 Sin[a] Sin[b], -a E^(I a c)},
{1, A, f[C, A]}}
```

I was trying to use Select, but I could not be able to do it because arbitrary function such as Cos, Sin, and Exp makes it difficult to separate. Any suggestion? Thank you

---

I modified list to make it easier to understand

Comment: So you want factors of each term containing `A, B, C` in  list 2, and the other factors in list 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function takes an expression and sorts its factors between a list of two elements depending on whether they contain one of A, B, C. From there it is easy to build what you want:

```
list={3 b, A Cos[c]^2 Sin[a] Sin[b], -a E^(I a c) f[C, A], B, 1, Pi};

factorByABC[expr_] := With[{x = Switch[expr, _Times, List@@expr, _, List@expr], hasABC = !FreeQ[#, A | B | C]&},
  Times @@@ {Select[x, Not@*hasABC], Select[x, hasABC]}
];

factorByABC /@ list // Transpose // Print

(* {{3*b, Cos[c]^2*Sin[a]*Sin[b], -(a*E^(I*a*c)), 1, 1, Pi}, {1, A, f[C, A], B, 1, 1}} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBfS8MwFMXf@ymOCNKGSJl7Uwppi4IgMunAh9CNLGQ0sLajDViJ/ew1/eNEH0Jyzr335PIrhSlUKYyWYhhOujWRXeNAESOtWy7z3R0yXXGRT9chp7gVeNz5zxCQAY48db3OTShWFBvdP3jeUUhTN8lnnKRcdedmn@M@wrs2BbcdImQf2shiKlHst7pULcWL@5uxxVvkqFx2IVoX5Qavnhql3vj1uN4XEnfS/KanHjCFgDEGm6mTkoZ3FK@1YWQedim//mL1Xv53WYQMIwKEIbaNqNpz3apRbBpdGc/zCaxdE0fnhw2Z2ZALG1@QEQ4RRAbBhGSmQmHdI6b/ga36HiQYhm8)

Comment: Thank you so muich!

Answer (score 3):

```
selectDiscard = Map[Select @ # @* FreeQ[a|b|c|_Integer]]& /@ {Not, Identity}

list = {3 b, A Cos[c]^2 Sin[a] Sin[b], -a E^(I a c) f[C, A]};
Through @ selectDiscard @ list
```

> {{3 b, Cos[c]^2 Sin[a] Sin[b], -a E^(I a c)},
>    {1, A, f[C, A]}}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FreeQ` and `Complement`:

```
list = {a*A*b*Cosh[c]^2, 3*b*c*Sinh[a], 
   Sinh[a]*Sinh[b]*A, -a*c*CenterDot[C, A]*E^(I*a*c)};

Union[Flatten[Outer[If[! FreeQ[#1, #2], #1, Nothing] &, list, {a, b, c}]]]

(* {-a c E^(I a c) C\[CenterDot]A, a A b Cosh[c]^2, 3 b c Sinh[a], A Sinh[a] Sinh[b]} *)

Union[Flatten[Outer[If[! FreeQ[#1, #2], #1, Nothing] &, list, {A, B, C}]]]

(* {-a c E^(I a c) C\[CenterDot]A, a A b Cosh[c]^2, A Sinh[a] Sinh[b]} *)

Complement[list, %, %%]

(* {} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, maybe my post was confusing, so I modified it. Please check :D